# Using Taylor series find derivatives of arctan(x)

Tags: integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Using Taylor series for $arctan(x)$, find $f^{(5)}(0)$ and $f^{(6)}(0)$ for $f(x)=arctan(x)$

I figure for this problem I compare the general Taylor series formula to the Taylor series for $arctan(x)$ and extract the derivatives form there.

$arctan(x) = 0 + x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\frac{x^9}{9}-\frac{x^{11}}{11}$

General Taylor series = $f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2+\frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3!}x^3+\frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!}x^4+\frac{f^{(5)}(0)}{5!}x^5+\frac{f^{(6)}(0)}{6!}x^6$

*Both series centered around $0$

5th term of $arctan(x)$ is $\frac{x^9}{9}$

5th term of the Taylor series is $\frac{f^5(0)}{5!}$

Set equal and solve for $f^5(0)$

After solving I get $f^5(0) = \frac{x^4*5!}{9}$ which equals $0$ when x equals $0$. The actual derivative at $x=0$ is 24 so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression for the Taylor series is wrong, it should be $$f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2 + \frac{f'''(0)}{3!}x^3 + \frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!}x^4 + \frac{f^{(5)}(0)}{5!}x^5 +  \ldots$$  What you've written isn't a power series, since each term after the second are constants rather than constants times powers of $x$.  (Also, you should be careful to not conflate finite Taylor **polynomials** with the infinite Taylor **series**.)

Equating the $5$-th term coefficients should instead yield $\frac{f^{(5)}(0)}{5!}x^5 = \frac{x^5}{5}$, and thus $\frac{f^{(5)}(0)}{5!} = \frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I must have forgotten the x values while trying to figure out LaTex. I think where I was actually having trouble was picking the right value for the 5th term from the Taylor series for arctan(x). You working out the problem helped me to see that, thank you very much.